# How to include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file THAT IS NOT RUN FROM INSIDE A BROWSER?

Tags: javascript, wsh

I know that many similar questions have been asked before. The difference in my case is that I am using Windows Scripting Host and am running the script from the DOS command line, not from inside a browser.

The only way I can think of doing this is to read the file from the disk as text using `fso.OpenTextFile(ThisFile, 1)`, and then using the `eval` function to treat the text as code.

Is there a more convenient way?

Comment: Googling for `wsh include file javascript` seems to turn up good solutions?

Comment: Yes it does seem like a duplicate, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, no, that's the only real option. Example:

`text.js`:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var ts = fso.OpenTextFile("foo.js");
var script = ts.ReadAll();
eval(script);
foo();
WScript.Echo(bar);
```

`foo.js`:

```
var bar = "testing";
function foo() {
    WScript.Echo("foo");
}
```

Output:

```
foo
testing
```