# Can you do imports in cscript JScript?

Tags: import, jscript, wsh

I'm making a library of JScripts and I want to be able to import a function into them.

Is there a way to do that?  Or am I just stuck replicating the function in every `.js` file I run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference a JScript file from another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054321/how-to-reference-a-jscript-file-from-another-one)

Comment: It takes a few minutes to search. Remember we are talking about a technology that is over 20+ years old now, it stands to reason this has been asked before.